# Kubuntu 19.10 screen saver activates HDMI sound and does not turn off screen

Tags: kubuntu, screensaver, 19.10

I've installed Kubuntu 19.10 twice with the same results.  When the screen energy savings timer is reached,  the sound is switched from the motherboard sound (the sound source I've set to default) to HDMI sound and the screen does not turn off.  I am using a Radeon 580 graphics card with the open source drivers.

What steps should I take next to trouble shoot this?

Edit:  the screen actually does turn off and if you move the mouse within about 10 seconds, the screen turns on and the sound is still through the motherboard.  If you do not move the mouse within about 10 seconds, the screen will turn on by itself and the sound will switch to the HDMI output.

Comment: The audio device swapping is being caused by PulseEffects version 4.6.8 installed via flatpack.  Closing PulseEffects resolves the audio source switching problem, but the screen saver still doesn't completely work.  It turns the screen off after the set time but then turns the screen back on after about 10 seconds.

Comment: Verified PulseEffects is not the problem.  Even with PulseEffects not running, the audio still switches.  
I then changed the input select (on the actual monitor screen menu) from "auto" to HDMI and now the screen saver works, but the sound out still switches with or without PulseEffects running.  The syslog output from before to now is very different.

Comment: I can reproduce the playback device switching from "built in analog" to HDMI just by doing pulseaudio -k.  It is looking like an initialization problem with pulseaudio.  The screen saver must be triggering the initialization, but why doesn't the pulseaudio init keep the the default setting of "built in analog?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of all the things I tried, I finally found one that worked, disabling the module that corresponds to the HDMI sound.  This removes the HDMI sound source.

1. Find the module number of the HDMI sound source (the output lists the module as "index:")

`pacmd list-modules`

I found that mine was 7.

2. To remove it do

`pacmd unload-module 7`

I put this in a script that runs  at system startup.  Now the screen saver and sound work (and continue to work) as expected.

Comment: What happens when you connect the computer to a different HDMI device, that does have sound? My setup is a laptop connected to a monitor without speakers, but I sometimes connect it to a TV via HDMI, and I want sound sent to the latter.

Comment: I update to each new Kubuntu version when it comes out, so now I am on 20.10.  I think the above stopped being an issue when I moved to 20.04.  It certainly isn't an issue now, so I can't answer your question.